# Ruby on Rails jobs NotImplementedError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jobs

I am trying to implement a Job in my Ruby on Rails application, but I keep getting this error:

```
NotImplementedError
```

Error from the server:

```
NotImplementedError (NotImplementedError):
  app/controllers/cron_controller.rb:6:in `message_10_minutes'
```

Here's the ActiveJob:

```
class TestSmsJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  #include Plivio

  def perform(*args)
    # do my stuff
  end
end
```

This is the call to the function for executing the job:

```
class CronController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def message_10_minutes
    TestSmsJob.set(wait: 10.minutes).perform_later()
    render :layout => false
  end
end
```

Do you guys know what am I missing?

Comment: which job adapter are you using?

Comment: None right now. The guide (http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) says that I need one only for production

Answer (score 0):

Rails by default comes with own implementation of asynchronous queuing however you still needs to specify which adapter do you want to use. If you want to use built in adapter you simply don't have to bundle any other gem.

Here is the list of adapters - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters.html

Since `sidekiq` may be too hard for the start you can use `sucker_punch` - https://github.com/brandonhilkert/sucker_punch

After you choose your adapter you have to update config

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Be sure to have the adapter's gem in your Gemfile
    # and follow the adapter's specific installation
    # and deployment instructions.
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :adapter_name
  end
end
```